# hawtio InstanceAlreadyExistsException type=security name=RBACRegistry

Tags: tomcat, apache-camel, hawtio

I tried running an example Camel application with hawtio which is listed in Hawtio getting stated page *(http://hawt.io/getstarted/index.html)* on Tomcat 8, and got the exception,

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class io.hawt.**HawtioContextListener**
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.**InstanceAlreadyExistsException**: **hawtio:type=security,name=RBACRegistry**
    at io.hawt.HawtioContextListener.createServletException(HawtioContextListener.java:61)
    at io.hawt.HawtioContextListener.contextInitialized(HawtioContextListener.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: hawtio:type=security,name=RBACRegistry
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(Unknown Source)
    at io.hawt.jmx.RBACRegistry.init(RBACRegistry.java:64)
    at io.hawt.HawtioContextListener.contextInitialized(HawtioContextListener.java:38)
    ... 9 more

Could someone please let me know what to do.

Comment: Hawtio changelog for version 1.4.66 states "Now every Jolokia call within Hawtio is checked based on RBAC. This means Hawtio is made more secure, but you may also encounter a bunch of access exceptions. Most of those exceptions are not a Hawtio bug, but just indicate lack of some necessary RBAC configurations on the container, e.g. Karaf ACL files. You can resolve those exceptions by fulfilling the required configurations on the running container." But I could not infer anything from it.

Comment: According to the error stacktrace, it doesn't look like this issue is related to the above changelog statement (btw 1.4.66 is not yet officially released).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: hawtio:type=security,name=RBACRegistry
```

It happened because your hawtio was trying to register `hawtio:type=security,name=RBACRegistry` to the MBean registry at initialisation but found that it was already registered somewhere else. I suspect that you have more than one hawtio instance deployed on Tomcat. If so, make sure you deploy only one hawtio instance on one application server.

If you are sure you deployed only one hawtio instance, then you need to check if `hawtio:type=security,name=RBACRegistry` really exists already by using some JMX client like JConsole to connect to the Tomcat server. Then find out where this MBean was registered.